# Why does bash -c '<instructions>' can't correctly capture my command?

Tags: bash, environment-modules, lmod

I am using environment modules on my Ubuntu container. https://modules.readthedocs.io

When I call the following command: `module av` It shows me this kind of output:

```
> module av
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- /project/mb/modulefiles --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
meco/bamtools/2.4.1  meco/bbmap/39.00      meco/bedtools/2.23.0  meco/bhtsne/1.0     meco/bwa/0.7.17  meco/diamond/2.1.6  meco/fastani/1.33   meco/fasttree/2.1.10  meco/hmmer/3.3.2  meco/mafft/7.471          meco/meco_tools/1.3.3  meco/metabat/2.12.1  meco/perl/5.38.0  meco/prodigal/2.6.3  meco/python/3.11.3  meco/R/4.3.1             meco/rtk/0.93.2    meco/SPAdes/3.15.0      meco/trimmomatic/0.39  meco/zlib/1.2.8  
meco/barrnap/0.9     meco/bedtools/2.22.1  meco/bedtools/2.29.2  meco/bowtie2/2.4.1  meco/CAT/5.2.3   meco/dnaclust/3     meco/fastqc/0.11.4  meco/fastx/0.0.13.2   meco/lftp/4.8.3   meco/meco_pipeline/1.3.3  meco/megahit/1.2.9     meco/muscle/3.8.31   meco/pplacer/1.1  meco/pTrimmer/1.3.4  meco/quast/5.2.0    meco/rdp_classifier/2.8  meco/samtools/1.9  meco/sratoolkit/2.10.9  meco/vsearch/2.7.1
```

However, if I run `bash -c 'module av'` it does not work:

```
# bash -c 'module av'
bash -c 'module av'
bash: line 1: module: command not found
```

From the faq, https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FAQ.html
the module command is actually a bash function.

*Edit:*
How can I make the `bash -c 'module av'` command show the same output as `module av`?

Please, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `export -f module` before calling `bash -c`.

Comment: It does the following (after doing the export): 

`> bash -c 'module av'
ERROR: Unknown shell type '(av)'`

Comment: Good, that solved the problem you asked about in your question then. Ask a new question about your new problem if after some time trying you can't figure it out for yourself.

Comment: You are correct, my question was not properly formulated. I've updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: It was specific and formulated just fine before, now you've made it open-ended ("keep helping me debug my code til it finally does what I want") and your current error message isn't even mentioned in the question so YMMV getting help with that. Good luck though. Neither my downvote nor my close vote btw.

Comment: Yes, I've already spent hours on this problem. This is why I'm coming for help here. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: I solved the problem you asked about, `bash: line 1: module: command not found`, which is presumably the problem you spent hours on. Now you have a completely different problem, `bash -c 'module av' ERROR: Unknown shell type '(av)'`, so I'm just suggesting you spend some time on that and then ask a new question if you need help with it. You're welcome.

Comment: Where does the module come from? A subshell won't run .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally opted to install and use Lmod instead of Environment modules. It now works. Although I still do not understand the root nature of the problem I had in my question.
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

The `bash: line 1: module: command not found` error is due to the bash session not being aware of the `module` shell function. It means that the initialization process of your `bash -c` command does not go through an initialization shell script that defines the `module` shell function.

You can enable this behavior on Environment Modules by setting the `set_shell_startup` to `1` in `/etc/environment-modules/initrc` configuration file.

Uncomment the following `module config` line in this configuration file:

```
# ensure that module command is still defined in sub-shells
#module config set_shell_startup 1
```

Then restart you shell session. You should get the `BASH_ENV` environment variable set and pointing to Modules initialization script.

```
$ echo $BASH_ENV
/usr/share/modules/init/bash
```

With `BASH_ENV` set this way, the Modules initialization script will be executed every time a bash shell is started.

Such option is disabled by default as it may increase bash initialization time a bit, which cannot be perceived for an interactive shell session but can have an effect when running shell scripts that creates sub-shells.